# filter list with StartsWith C#

Tags: c#, .net

there is a list of words in the .txt file. I want to show by console only the words that begin with the letter 'R' and that preserve the alphabetical order. example:
'Rav'
'Ret'
'Ril'

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(
                @"C:\Users\thoma\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Backup Files\data.txt");



            string orden = "";
            List<string> arrText = new List<string>();

            while (orden != null)
            {
                orden = objReader.ReadLine();
                if (orden != null) arrText.Add(orden);
            }
            objReader.Close();

           foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
                Console.WriteLine(sOutput);

            Console.WriteLine("Order alphabetically ascending press 'a': ");
            Console.WriteLine("Ordener descendant alphabetical press 'b': ");                       

            instruccion = Console.ReadLine();
            if (instruccion == "a"){
                var resultList = arrText.Where(o => o.StartsWith("r"));
                Console.WriteLine(resultList);    
//string ascending = string.Format("{0}{1}{0}", "'", string.Join("','", arrText.OrderBy(x => x)));


            }         
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

the result that this code gives me is '**System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator**'

**thanks for your help**

Comment: Your `arrText` is not a string so it just prints out its type rather than its value.  Try using `string.Join(arrText, ", ")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must iterate the result list, just like you did the `arrText` values earlier.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileName = @"C:\Users\thoma\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Backup Files\data.txt";
    var arrText = File.ReadLines(fileName).ToList();         

    foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
        Console.WriteLine(sOutput);

    Console.WriteLine("Order alphabetically ascending press 'a': ");
    Console.WriteLine("Ordener descendant alphabetical press 'b': ");                       

    var instruccion = Console.ReadLine();
    IEnumerable<string> resultList;
    if (instruccion == "a")
        resultList = arrText.Where(o => o.ToLower().StartsWith("r")).OrderBy(o => o);
    else if (instruccion == "b")
         resultList = arrText.Where(o => o.ToLower().StartsWith("r")).OrderByDescending(o => o);
    else
        resultList = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    foreach(var item in resultList)
        Console.WriteLine(item);    

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The console.writeline is simply printing the objects ToString() method, which is the name of the object in this case.

You need to enumerate the result ... Maybe something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", resultList))
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass to Console.WriteLine an Ienumerable object:

```
Console.WriteLine(resultList);
```

But you dont want print the object element (the container), but each element, so you need iterate the result and print each them:

```
foreach(var element in resultList)
    Console.WriteLine(element);
```